# hash each line in text file

Tags: bash, command-line, hash

I'm trying to write a little script which will open a text file and give me an md5 hash for each line of text. For example I have a file with:

```
123
213
312
```

I want output to be:

```
ba1f2511fc30423bdbb183fe33f3dd0f
6f36dfd82a1b64f668d9957ad81199ff
390d29f732f024a4ebd58645781dfa5a
```

I'm trying to do this part in bash which will read each line:

```
#!/bin/bash
#read.file.line.by.line.sh

while read line
do
echo $line
done
```

later on I do:

```
$ more 123.txt | ./read.line.by.line.sh | md5sum | cut -d '  ' -f 1
```

but I'm missing something here, does not work :(

Maybe there is an easier way...

Answer (score 38):

Almost there, try this:

```
while read -r line; do printf %s "$line" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d' '; done < 123.txt
```

Unless you also want to hash the newline character in every line you should use `printf` or `echo -n` instead of `echo` option.

In a script:

```
#! /bin/bash
cat "$@" | while read -r line; do
    printf %s "$line" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d' '
done
```

The script can be called with multiple files as parameters.

Comment: Or pass the string to md5's stdin without "echo": md5 <<< "$line"

Comment: @glenn jackman Your example will also hash the newline character of each line which changes the hash of the string.

Answer (score 6):

You can just call md5sum directly in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#read.file.line.by.line.sh

while read line
do
echo $line | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
done
```

That way the script spits out directly what you want: the md5 hash of each line.

Comment: You should probably put the awk outside loop, to avoid spawning an unnecessary instance of it for each line.  Just do `done | awk '{print $1}'`.

Comment: You should do echo -n $line because by default, echo adds a newline to the end of the string. Consequently, it changes the MD5 value of the string.

Comment: His example included the newline in the hash...  I checked the values.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me..

cat $file | while read line; do printf %s "$line" | tr -d '\r\n' | md5 >> hashes.csv; done

Comment: Your file had DOS terminated lines, which is a different problem. The correct way would have been: `sed 's/^M$//' "$file" | while read -r line; do printf %s "$line" | md5; done >> hashes.txt`